# Problem in query string in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have Install and develop a new website in Joomla 1.5.20.

When I have create a menu for the following external url.

```
index.php?option=com_astroservices&task=displayServices&Itemid=54
```

If click that link in the browser address bar. it displaying the url link this.

```
http://localhost:81/astrology/index.php/component/astroservices/?task=displayServices
```

But i want link display link follows:

```
http://localhost:81/astrology/index.php?oprion=com_astroservices&task=displayServices
```

Any one can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have activated SEF URLs inside Joomla. Check the Joomla configuration dialog and check if you have an .htaccess file in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is used for my reference:

http://www.joomlatutorials.com/joomla-tips-and-tricks/38-joomla-website-management/87-configuring-joomla-sef-urls.html